# Is it Preference relation?

Tags: derivatives, relations, order-theory

I need to check if the relation $ \succeq ( \space  \succeq \space \subset   X × X, \space X=VB[0,1] ) $ define as below $$ f \succeq g \Longleftrightarrow Var(f+g) \geq Varf $$
is preference relation. If it is preferance relation then is it represented by any utility function ?

I have no idea how to slove it with good explanation, i want to understand how i schoud deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation is called – mostly in economics terminology – *preference relation* if is reflexive, transitive, and dichotomous.

Az $R$ relation on an $X$ set is called

- [*reflexive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation), if for all $x \in X$: $(x,x) \in R$;
- [*transitive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), if for all $x,y,z \in X$ if $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$ then $(x,z) \in R$;
- *dichotomous* or [*total*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation), if for all $x,y \in R$ $(x,y) \in R$ or $(y,x) \in R$ (possibly both) holds.

So to answer the first question we have to check the properties.

- reflexivity: $\operatorname{Var}(f+f)=\operatorname{Var}(2f) = 4\operatorname{Var}(f) \geq \operatorname{Var}(f)$
- etc $\dots$ I let you the rest! Check it!

To the second part of the problem you have to check that the relation is continous of not. $\succeq$ is countinous on $X$ is for all $x,y,z \in X$ the sets
$\{ \alpha \in [0,1] \mid \alpha x+(1-\alpha)y \succeq z \}$ and $\{ \alpha \in [0,1] \mid z \succeq \alpha x+(1-\alpha)y  \}$ sets are closed. You just have to check it.

Comment: My result is that it is continous relation. Right ? if not i will check again till i find.
I have second question also can i say from the definition that this is utility function ? It looks like it is given, becasue if $\space$ $f$ is in relation with $g$ then u(f) $\geq$ u(g), but in other hadn i have in this exercise u(f+g) $\geq$ u(f).

Comment: If beside the continouty there is also independency, so
for all $x,y,z \in X$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$ there is $$x \succeq y \iff \alpha x + (1-\alpha)z \succeq \alpha y + (1-\alpha) z$$ then you can represent your relation with utility function.